# SAS "More positional parameters found than defined" with proc sql in a macro

Tags: sql, database, sas

I am encountering the error "More positional parameters found than defined" for the following code:

```
%let my_list_of_vars = x, y, z;

%macro sumstats(my_vars);

proc sql;
    create table test2 as
    select distinct &my_vars.
    from my_dataset;
quit;

%mend sumstats;

%sumstats(&my_list_of_vars.);
```

I'm not quite sure why the proc sql isn't taking in my list of variables "x", "y", and "z", and is instead returning that error. I've looked online and cannot seem to find solutions to this issue. For instance, this website (http://support.sas.com/kb/31/012.html) suggests using %put or %bquote, but neither work. Would much appreciate some guidance.

Thank you.

Comment: How did you use %bquote, and what went wrong?

Comment: Thanks!! The answer that Reeza provides below using %bquote is absolutely correct. I realize that I was, incorrectly, defining my variables using %put (instead of %let) and then adding %bquote in the macro function. Correcting the %put to %let has fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code resolves to the following, so you need to mask the comma's in the macro call.

```
%sumstats(x, y, z);
```

INCORRECT: Try using `%str()`

```
%sumstats(%str(&my_list_of_vars.));
```

EDIT: 
You have example 2, so %BQUOTE() is correct.

```
%sumstats(%BQUOTE(&my_list_of_vars.));
```

SAS Note regarding this issue and solutions:
http://support.sas.com/kb/31/012.html

Comment: I would expect this to require an execution-time quoting function such as %bquote.

Comment: Many thanks Reeza! I have added a comment above regarding why %bquote wasn't working for me earlier. It is now.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to use commas as a delimiter in a list of variable names.  That is not very useful in normal SAS code and leads to headaches and confusion when trying use them in function calls or macro calls.  Instead add the commas when you need them.

```
%macro sumstats(my_vars);
* Normal SAS code ;
proc sort data=my_dataset(keep=&my_vars) out=test1 nodupkey;
run;

* Make version of list with commas for use in PROC SQL code ;
%local my_varsc ;
%let my_varsc = %sysfunc(compbl(&my_vars));
%let my_varsc = %sysfunc(translate(&my_varsc,',',' '));
proc sql;
  create table test2 as
    select distinct &my_varsc
    from my_dataset
  ;
quit;

%mend sumstats;

%let my_list_of_vars = x y z;
%sumstats(&my_list_of_vars.);
```

Comment: Hi Tom! The above seems to be the most direct solution. But I've tried out your solution, and it works excellently. Definitely seems like this is a best practice that I should use going forward, and I intend to. I don't really know much about the translate or compbl functions, so I'm looking into those now. I'll certainly write back here with any questions. Thanks!

Comment: Got it! I see what you're doing. You're taking the variable and compressing it using compbl so that there is only 1 space between "x y z" (as opposed to multiple spaces like  "x     y    z") and then using the translate function to add commas in the spaces to make it "x, y, z" inside the macro. Did I get that correct? This looks like the solution I'll be using moving forward. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes. The COMPBL() makes sure there are not multiple spaces so you don't end up  with `A,,B`.  The single quotes are just so I didn't have to use macro quotes around the comma and the space in the translate() call.  `TRANSLATE()` will convert the spaces to commas and the quotes to quotes.

Comment: Thanks! Really helpful.